# Paging no longer works after off/on to redo "buildingQuery"

Tags: coveo

I did a ham-handed way of building my own facets and resetting the query, by doing this:

```
Coveo.$('#search').off(Coveo.QueryEvents.buildingQuery)
Coveo.$('#search').on(Coveo.QueryEvents.buildingQuery, createQuery)
Coveo.$('#search').coveo('executeQuery');
```

Where "createQuery" is my query that sets up all of the search criteria. The catch seems to be that when I do this, it knocks out pagination...I see the paging, but clicking a page number or the arrow to move forward just causes the section to fade out and in without changing pages.

How can I either rebind pagination, or is there a way to quickly reset this to requery Coveo (call my "createQuery" function) without doing off/on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Coveo.$('#search').off(Coveo.QueryEvents.buildingQuery)` not only removes your event, but *every other event bound to* `buildingQuery`.

Looking at [the Pager code](https://github.com/coveo/search-ui/blob/master/src/ui/Pager/Pager.ts#L216) in the `coveo-search-ui`, its `buildingQuery` event updates the query like so:

```
data.queryBuilder.firstResult = eventArgs.first;
data.queryBuilder.numberOfResults = eventArgs.count;
```

If this event is not triggered, `firstResult` and `numberOfResults` would not be updated, thus stalling the pager.

I really think you should *not* call `.off(Coveo.QueryEvents.buildingQuery)` as I suspect it will disable every other events that were bound to it.

I would instead suggest to bind your `buildingQuery` event once in your component initialization. If you needed that `.off` to temporarily disable your `buildingQuery`, put this condition directly in your `createQuery` instead to add your own information to the query *only* when needed.

Comment: Also `Coveo.$('#search').on(Coveo.QueryEvents.buildingQuery, createQuery)` needs to be called only once at the initialization of your search interface. The event handler will be registered once and used every time the search interface needs to build a query for the entire lifetime of the search interface. You generally do not need to unregister your event handler.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So assuming all of my query-building data is in my "createQuery" function, what's the best way to re-execute the function to generate a fresh search result, based on changing criteria? I'm just using standard jQuery to run through my custom checkboxes, etc, to set up the query conditions. I think if I get that right, I don't need to do the .off bit and I spare myself the entire hassle you've correctly pointed out.

Comment: Since the `buildingQuery` event is triggered every time a query is executed, all you have to do is inject the right values in `createQuery` depending on what is selected in your facet. You can then do a regular `.coveo("executeQuery")` to "refresh" the results.

Comment: It's always the easiest thing...perfect. Thanks!